# removed extension name still displaying in home page

Tags: google-analytics

we installed **woopra** extension for google analytics.

after that we removed this extension by removing all files of this extension.
but when we  open this [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/), please observe at left bottom, still you can see **woopra.com** at the time of loading. i really dont know from where this is coming and i want to remove this permanently.

Comment: which version of magento are you using 2 or 1.x?

Comment: i did not see anything

Comment: please refrsh the page again and observe at left bottom

Comment: If you have removed all the extension's files, the only place this can be coming from is one of many caches. Clear your Magento cache, your Magento compiler, your opcache (these remove any code being executed from memory), then your full page cache and finally your browser cache.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Thanks for your valuable hints. We missly added in cms pages. so it was reflecting. now we removed it.

Comment: Ah, yes, if there was a javascript or quick link added to one of those, then it wouldn't disappear till that reference was removed. You're welcome! All the places where things can get stuck in Magento... can keep you awake at night!

Comment: Oh, yes.... because of these strange magento problems, i am working day & night :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all files are deleted, my guess is that there is something in the database left.

If you have access to it I would recommend to start searching in these tables for the woopra string:

- core_config_data (column: value)
- cms_page (column: content)
- cms_block (column: content)

**===UPDATE===**
the mysql queries to find these:

```
select path,value from core_config_data where value like "%woopra%";
select block_id,content from cms_block where content like "%woopra%";
select page_id,content from cms_page where content like "%woopra%"
```

Comment: i will try that....

Comment: can you please give database query , so that i can search word "woopra" in entire database table

Comment: when i ran 3rd query, i got following result : http://prntscr.com/a0on1q

Comment: this code was there in db content : http://pastebin.com/5TaJNvc6 , how to remove this ?

Comment: thats it i think ;) just saw you cant filter the cms pages in backend by id. But you can just open any CMS Page (in the backend) and then replace the number in the url behind page_id with the 27605. Then you can inspect the content for anything from woopra

Comment: for this link http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/index.php/andios/cms_page/edit/page_id/27600/key/0a4af465e1874ab8914bfc1989e0d182/ , i changed 27605 instead of 27600. than page i saw "page no longer exists", i am missing somewhere. please guide me.

Comment: hm ok, you can also change the content directly in phpmyadmin, but its a bit less comfortable to use / read. Just execute the query again and klick on the edit button to the left

Comment: aaah just saw it, it was 27602, not 5 :D   The id field from your query

Comment: you did a miracle.... can't believe it......